# Python script unable to access external drive under cron

Tags: security, permission, external-disk, python, cron

My desired cron job consists of a bash script that does the following:

- Create a new Python environment (with a new python executable)
- Use that Python executable to run a Python script, which accesses an external hard drive

How do I create a job like this on macOS?

My issue is that cron and executables under cron do not have access to external drives by default. I typically work around this by manually allowing "Full Disk Access". For example, I have given my cron and rsync executables full disk access already, which solved their respective issues with disk access.

However, I am unable to give the python executable full disk access manually since I am creating a new python executable for each job that runs.

It would be great if I could programmatically give my new python executable access to the external drive, or just disable the need for "Full Disk Access" entirely, but I haven't found a way to accomplish either of those.

Comment: I've given python itself FDA.

Comment: @benwiggy The issue is I need to create a new python executable (aka python interpreter) in each job. So I can't just give a single python interpreter FDA and call it a day. I need to give each new interpreter FDA.

(I assumed by "python itself" you meant a python interpreter.)

Comment: In my case, I mean `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11`. Are you saying you need to create a new 'one of those', for every job? Can't you use a virtual environment? Perhaps explain what you want to achieve, and maybe there's another way of doing it.

Comment: Indeed, I am downloading and creating a new one of those for each job. What my job does is basically test an installation script for a piece of software. That installation script downloads its own python interpreter (at a specific version) and creates a virtual environment. The idea is so the user doesn't have to worry about getting the right Python version installed.

Comment: If a script could give itself permission to access external disks, that would circumvent the whole point of FDA. (Though I'm with you that a user-authorised script should be able to do anything.) What's on the external disk?